# New class base on book class with options

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

I created a class of my own that uses `book` as base class.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{manuscript}[2013/03/23 Creative writing manuscripts class]
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
```

The problem is that I want to be able to choose paper size and other options the `book` class has. The only way to do that is to redefine all the options the `book` class already has with the same values and pass it when I load the base class?

Also, let's say I want to add a language option to my class so that if I choose Portuguese, for example, I want to load `babel` with portuguese.

How can I create use the options already defined in `book` class to change the values of that class and use my new Portuguese option to load `babel` with that language.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
```

to pass all not used option to your basic class book when it is called with `\LoadClass{book}`.

To give you a better advice you should add a MWE what you doing in your class.

Comment: Ah, understood.

And what about the babel package?
My idea was to use \documentclass[portuguese,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{newClass}
And get just the portuguese option to make something like
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
with that option instead hardcoding it inside the class.

Comment: Btw, here's the source code of my class https://github.com/efernandespt/Manuscript/blob/master/manuscript.cls

I'm trying to use \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\LoadClass{book} and get this error \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options selection

Answer (score 2):

To pass the options, use

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions \relax
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
```

To pass a new option to another package (in this case babel)

```
\DeclareOption{english}{\AtEndOfClass{\main@language{english}}}
\DeclareOption{portuguese}{\AtEndOfClass{\main@language{portuges}}}
\RequirePackage[portuges, english]{babel}
```