# handout option for the class bredelebeamer don't work

Tags: beamer

There is a class called [bredelebeamer](https://git.framasoft.org/Framatophe/BredeleDiapo/tree/master) that I use for a while now to create my presentations. I like the colors and all.

I remarked that this class does not support handout option that eliminates the work of all \pause at once.
I tried to renewcommand pause like this: `\renewcommand{\pause}{ }`, but this gives an error saying that pause is undefined.

Is there a way to get around this problem, to create a handout for my presentation without deleting pause commands one by one?

Comment: how about `\renewcommand{\pause}{\relax}`?

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. To feedback, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. samcarter solution worked well.

Comment: Indeed it didn't work - it was just a quick guess :) The following does work: `\makeatletter \renewcommand{\beamer@@pause}{\relax} \makeatother`. But the solution by @samcarter is much better for creating an actual handout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Bredelebeamer` does not pass any class option on to `beamer`. I also find it very strange that this is done as a class and not as a beamer theme ....

However you can manually tell beamer that it should be in `handout` mode:

```
\documentclass{Bredelebeamer}

\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
    \pause
    cdf
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or add code to the class for passing options (e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111958/new-class-base-on-book-class-with-options) and then use `\documentclass[handout]{Bredelebeamer}` directly.

Comment: @Marijn Though first check the license before modifying a foreign class file.

Comment: Good point. In this case the license is GNU-GPL v3 so modifications are allowed (with a few conditions). It might be better (and helpful to other others of the class) to ask the class author to make the modifications.

Comment: @Marijn It would certainly be better to raise this problem to the author (there are also some other problems in the class file and unnecessary packages) - however the bugtracker requires a login to `git.framasoft.org` which I do not have.

Comment: @samcarter this was my first thought before asking here, but I can't find his email.